# My selenium script throws error .Does anyone knows how to solve it

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When I am writing the selenium script = Wait wait=new FluentWait(driver) .It should not throw errors even after importing the respective classes.Does anyone know how to solve it

Comment: Please see - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Kumar Satyajit: Can you put some code in your question and the error message